# Making service calls using ServiceStack and a C# client with Windows Authentication throws Unauthorized exception

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack, windows-authentication

I have a server which exposes a set of REST services. I'm consuming those services in a WPF client. All this works in an Intranet and recently I decided to turn Windows authentication on (until now i was using a different form of authentication) so I can achieve SSO.
When I enabled IWA all services remained accessible when invoked through a browser. The problem is when I invoke them using a C# client (JsvServiceClient - a ServiceStack class) i get Unauthorized exception. I am using Negotiate because I need Kerberos for Impersonation/Delegation on the server.

**Some thoughts on my own:**

When i run fiddler it seems that under the covers, when the browser makes its first request it receives unauthorized as well but after that it sends another request with Authorization: Negotiate ygMDAuBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKB (this token is longer, i've shortened it for simplicity) in the header. Doing this causes Unauthorized again. After that a 3rd request is sent which again has Authorization: Negotiate in the header (but with different token after that). This time the request is authorized and the data is displayed.

I know how authentication, authorization, caching and so on works in SS but the thing is that on the server no code gets called (when using JsvServiceClient). I created an HttpModule and added it to the web config just for debug purposes. HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest is fired and immediately after that Unathorized is thrown. So apparently the call is rejected at this level and, as SS is mainly HttpHandlers put to work together, no server code (handlers not reached at all) is triggered.

It is possible that browsers execute some logic on their own that handles WindowsAuth (some kind of handshake or sth) and that this logic is not handled using C# clients in SS. But as I am not sure of that I decided to ask all the gurus here.

May be this is a stupid question but apparently i can't figure it out on my own so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding a `RequestFilter` to the client you can sets the credentials to the current logged in user, the same way the browser does for you.

See [`CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx) for more info.

```cs
JsvServiceClient client = new JsvServiceClient("https://host:port/");
...
client.RequestFilter = req => {
    req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
};
```

To address your specific concerns:

> It is possible that browsers execute some logic on their own that handles WindowsAuth (some kind of handshake or sth) and that this logic is not handled using C# clients in SS.

Yes browsers do handle the Windows Authentication on their own when accessing from an Intranet zone. But the underlying `HttpWebRequest` in the ServiceStack client, `JsvServiceClient`, will need to be configured to send the credentials *as shown above*.

> I know how authentication, authorization, caching and so on works in SS but the thing is that on the server no code gets called

IIS provides the Windows Authentication layer, not ServiceStack, so no code in your ServiceStack service is called until the Windows Authentication succeeds. Only then will the request be passed to the ServiceStack handler.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Apparently it was kind of a dumb question as I expected. Marking as answer. Thanks, man.